# React-Native text not going on two rows

Tags: css, react-native

So, my problem is I have a text and it cuts after the first line, if it doesn't fit.
For example `lorem ipsum what...` it should say `lorem ipsum whatever` but it doesn't fit.
My text has the following styles

```
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
paddingVertical:4;
alignItems:flex-start
```

Could it be the flex-start that makes my text stay on one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass this props **ellipsizeMode="tail"** and  **numberOfLines={1}**

Answer (score 1):

you can use numberOfLines={1} props in Text component